# Whats a practical and safe encryption to use today?

Tags: public-key, symmetric, provable-security

I'm new to making applications that encrypt sensitive data and so don't know where to start.

My question is what is a good encryption scheme that can be run in a good time for normal application and is secure?

I would really like one symmetric and one asymmetric method but would settle for symmetric.

Comment: Its pretty much what I wanted, but I found that all the answers to the question and the question itself where posted a long time ago. For example 2014 now its 2022, So I don't know how much of that is still up to date. Can you point out what is.

Comment: Im sorry if its a bit too asky of a question, I'm just worried because this will be a product people use to encrypt private data and I don't want to mislead them by making something that is easily craked.

Comment: too too broad, need to focus it or it will be closed. define "a normal application". protect private data against which types of adversaries, which type of scenarios?